# IntelliJ & Jetty configuration takes a lot of time to open browser after launch

Tags: intellij-idea, jetty

I have a legacy `Java` application that runs in `Jetty`.

When I run it in `IntelliJ` in Windows 10, with the Jetty configuration (`Edit configuration -> Jetty Server`), there is an option to open a browser after the launch of the application.

I found that if the option if `off`, it takes about 2-3 minutes for the application to start and be accessible.

But if the option is `open browser after launch` (using Chrome), it takes the app more time to spin up (to reach the "Started @...") and it takes **an additional few more minutes** till the browser opens up. Also, in the log, it seems like it is closing the application after it started:

```
2020-04-23 14:43:05.846:INFO:oejs.Server:main: Started @183098ms
         Connected to server
2020-04-23 14:43:06.076:INFO:bla.mywebapp:RMI TCP Connection(6)-8.8.8.8: Closing Spring root WebApplicationContext
```

Any reason that can make this long delay in opening the bowser so much time after the application is already up?

And why it seems like it is closing the app in order to launch the browser?

Comment: Have you tried to compare the behaviour if open browser manually? Do you see same messages? Also add informaiton about the OS and the browser.

Comment: Turn on Jetty debug logging, there should be timing output telling you what it's doing (opening war, preparing libs, preparing resources, scanning bytecode, etc...).